# Low performance of groupbykey in spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

After reading the Spark documentation, I find that `groupByKey` function has a low performance compared with `reduceByKey`. But what I need is to get the `average`, `maximum` and `minimum` value of a certain key. I don't think this could be done by `reduceByKey` method. I can just create an customized `reduceByKey` function to realize those goals?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't compute `avg`, `max`, and `min` with `reduceByKey`. Did you try something already?

Comment: `reduceByKey(Partitioner partitioner, Function2<V,V,V> func)
Merge the values for each key using an associative reduce function.` Above is the reduceByKey function using `Java`. How can you maintain a `max` value and `min` value within a `Function2`? If you have multiple nodes, the `reduce` step will go to those nodes, then how can you compare them since they are on different node? @maasg

Comment: Can you take a look at this question?  @maasg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260756/spark-flatmaptopair-to-create-keys-of-different-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have an `RDD[(String, Double)]` and you want to calculate avg, min, max over the double values using `reduceByKey`. 
This could by done by duplicating the values as many times as operations you like to apply and then applying the different operations with `reduceByKey`.

Like this:

```
val srcData:RDD[(String, Double)] = ???
srcData.cache
val count = srcData.count
val baseData = srcData.map{case (k,v) => (k,(v,1,v,v))}
val aggregates = baseData.reduceByKey { case (v1,v2) => 
    (v1._1 + v2._1, v1._2 + v2._2, Math.max(v1._3, v2._3), Math.min(v1._4,v2._4))}
val result = aggregates.collect()
            .map{case (id, (sum, count, max, min)) => (id, sum/count, max, min)}
```

Comment: I am a bit confused about the `scala` format since I am using `Java`. So after all these, you use a `total/count` to get the `average`?

Comment: @Liquid improved the code a bit to better show the usage and result.