# spark flatMapToPair to create keys of different type

Tags: java, apache-spark, flatmap

For the following codes using `spark` `java` API:

```
JavaPairRDD<TypeOne,Long> pairs = originalRows.flatMapToPair(new PairFlatMapFunction<OriginalType,TypeOne,Long>()
```

it takes the `RDD`, named `OriginalType` and maps it into pairs with key type of `TypeOne`.

I am wondering that is it possible to takes `OriginalType` and during the map step, maps it into two types of key? Like `TypeOne` and `TypeTwo`. Or I must use two map steps to realize this...

Comment: Think about what would be the expected type of the resulting RDD.

Comment: Are the Types defined by you? In such case you could perhaps have both of them inherit from a generic parent, and have the tuple be formed by the generic case.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Interface or Generic class that both types will implement/inherit and use this instead of the specific type.

```
public interface IType { }

public class TypeOne implements IType { }

public class TypeTwo implements IType { }

JavaPairRDD<IType,Long> pairs = originalRows.flatMapToPair(new PairFlatMapFunction<OriginalType,IType,Long>()
```